# google maps nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-maps

Is it allowed to use google maps in the server side without actually displaying the map? I've searched around and it seems it is not but I cans see there are nodeJs plugins for Google Maps. I would like to use the directionService with node js. If it is allowed do I need to put the Google logo somewhere?

Thanks

EDIT:
Here's how I've done it [gist](https://gist.github.com/nicco/0e10cb0a8254f1b4c721)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely free to call the API from your node server – it's [a simple REST request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON) – but the [terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1) (10.1.1(g)) require you to ultimately display the results on a Google Map.

Comment: So just to recap, I can get the directions in the backend, run my logic against them in the backend but then I need to forward them to the client to be displayed in a google map

Comment: 10.1.1(g) has now been removed and as far as I see it does not apper anywhere else